# In Java, Can the Date type just hold MM-dd-yyyy or just hh:mm:ss?

Tags: java

I am converting epoch format time to the normal format, but when I convert it to date I get, MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss.

If I want to single out just the date or the time I have to use SimpleDateFormat. But this returns a String. I was wondering if there was a way to make this string a Date type.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.  Please show some example code.

Comment: "when I convert it to date I get, MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss." a date is a date, it has no format

Comment: A date is a single point in time while a time is a repeating point in time (every day) and depending on the timezone. On the other hand, a _day_ is a time period and even if you just provide the day, month and year, you'll get a single timestamp (with time being 00:00:00,000). However, Java 8 has classes like `LocalTime` which might be what you're after.

Comment: Read the Javadoc to find out what `Date` is: "The class `Date`represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision." So no, it cannot be something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type `java.util.Date` is actually a timestamp, it is not much more than a wrapper for a number of milliseconds since 01-01-1970, 00:00:00 UTC. (The class name `Date` is unfortunately badly chosen).

It is not very well suited for holding just a date or just a time value.

If you are using Java 8, use the new date and time API (package `java.time`); use for example [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) if you need to store a year/month/day, or a [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) if you need to store just a time-of-day (hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds).

If you are using Java 7 or older, consider using the equivalent classes in the [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

Comment: Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted to Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. The Joda-Time team advises migrating to java.time.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the date as MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss not (MM-dd-yyyy **hh**:mm:ss)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
DateFormat dateformat= new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = dateformat.parse("01-25-1988 23:54:59");
System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(dateformat.format(date));
```

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/simpledateformat.html